# Access a user's Google Calendar events once having logged into a web app

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am creating a Node JS (Express) web app that will display a user's Google Calendar events, once they have logged in.

There will be multiple users, with data such as name and email address stored in a database.

---

Once a user has logged in, how can I retrieve a user's Google Calendar events associated to them without requiring any additional user input?

I have implemented Google's quick start sample here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs

However this provides only access to a single authenticated user (authenticated via a terminal authentication process), with no opportunity to request a calendar of another user.

-

**Question**

How can I authenticate multiple users via a signup page (rather than using the nodeJS terminal) and access these google calendar events later via the data stored in a database? (Server side, with no interaction required )

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Domain Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth#perform-google-apps-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority) in the Service Account. It is stated [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) that:

> If you have a Google Apps domain—if you use Google Apps for Work, for
>   example—an administrator of the Google Apps domain can authorize an
>   application to access user data on behalf of users in the Google Apps
>   domain. For example, an application that uses the Google Calendar API
>   to add events to the calendars of all users in a Google Apps domain
>   would use a service account to access the Google Calendar API on
>   behalf of users. Authorizing a service account to access data on
>   behalf of users in a domain is sometimes referred to as "delegating
>   domain-wide authority" to a service account.

Just remember that you need a service account here to enable the domain wide authority. For more information, just read this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). It also discussed here on how to [create service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount).